# Flows: Escape Lemma

Tags: differential-geometry

Denote compact sets by: $\mathcal{C}$

Given a smooth manifold.

Consider the maximal flow of a smooth vector field:
$$V\in\mathscr{V}(M):\quad\dot{\Phi}_x(t)=V_{\Phi_x(t)}\quad(\alpha(x)<t<\omega(x))$$

Then the birth resp. death time is lower resp. upper semicontinuous:
$$U^-_x\in\mathcal{T}:\quad\alpha(U^-_x)\leq\alpha(x)+\varepsilon$$
$$U^+_x\in\mathcal{T}:\quad\omega(x)-\varepsilon\leq\omega(U^+_x)$$
*(Note that they're not locally decreasing resp. increasing in general.)*

Thus semifinite maximal integral curves must escape compact regions:
$$\alpha(x)>\infty:\quad\Phi_x(\alpha(x),0]\nsubseteq\Omega\quad(\Omega\in\mathcal{C})$$
$$\omega(x)<\infty:\quad\Phi_x[0,\omega(x))\nsubseteq\Omega\quad(\Omega\in\mathcal{C})$$
*(In fact, regarding zero as threshold does not lose generality.)*

So that compactly supported vector fields are complete:
$$V\in\mathscr{X}(M):\quad\mathrm{supp}V\in\mathcal{C}\implies\mathcal{D}(\Phi_x)\equiv\mathbb{R}$$
*(Especially, on compact manifolds all vector fields are complete.)*

How do I prove the semicontinuity of birth and death time?

Comment: You got the idea, but perhaps should use other term than  locally increasing/decreasing. The proper statement is : $\alpha(\cdot)$ is upper semicontinuous, $\omega(\cdot)$ is lower semicontinuous. They are consequences of the fact that the domain of the maximal flow $D \subset \mathbb{R} \times X$ is open in $\mathbb{R} \times X$. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_flow.  Perhaps the book of V. I. Arnold on Ordinary Differential Equations might have a good presentation of this.

Comment: @orangeskid: Aah actually it may not be locally increasing/decreasing. *'dough'* Ok so I know that the domain is open as ODE's are locally solvable and then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fact that the domain is open follows from local solvability and uniqueness (  a bit of a challenge to prove). 
Note that the domain $D$ of the maximal vector flow is

$$D= \cup_{x \in X} (\alpha(x), \omega(x))$$
Take $x_0 \in X$ and $ \alpha '$ in the interval $ ( \alpha(x_0), 0)$. Then the pair $(\alpha', x_0)$ is in $D$. Since $D$ is open there exists $\delta > 0$ and $V$ open containing $x_0$ so that
$$[\alpha' - \delta, \alpha' + \delta] \times V \subset D$$
This implies $\alpha(x) \le \alpha'- \delta < \alpha'$ for all $x \in V$.

Comment: Ok, got it, thanks! :)

Comment: Do you have any source or direction for the fact that the domain is open?

Comment: @JefferyOpoku-Mensah:  sorry, but I don't have a source at hand right now. A fairly detailed book on ODE's should contain it.